# I can't take value from dictionary in my django project

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-models, key-value

I have the dictionary shown below:

```
duties = {
    1 : 'Crew',
    2 : 'Cast',
    3 : 'Director',
    4 : 'Writers',
}`

{% with index=person.duty_type %}
                        
<div class="small text-gray-500">{{duties.index}}</div>
                            
{% endwith %}
```

The spesific value i choose from dictionary doesn't display in site.

I also have tried to write it like this:

```
<div class="small text-gray-500">{{duties.person.duty_type}}</div>
```

None of the solutions i have tried worked.

Comment: No subscripting is deliberately not done in Django's template langauge. You should do this in the view.

Comment: Can you share the model for `person`?

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the context data from view to use them in template.

```
class SampleListView(ListView):

    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SampleListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # you should modify following dict
        context["data_you_want_to_use"] =  {
              1 : 'Crew',
              2 : 'Cast',
              3 : 'Director',
              4 : 'Writers',
        }
    return context

    ...
```

then, you can use "data_you_want_to_use" in template as follows.

```
<div>
    {% for key, data in data_you_want_to_use.items %}
        {{ data }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Django's template language does *not* support subscripting (i.e. `x[y]`), this has been done deliberately to prevent people from writing *business logic* in the templates. One can use [*Jinja*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/) as a template language, but this is not necessary and to some extent counterproductive, precisely to prevent writing business logic in the template.

However, it is often not necessary at all. For example in this specific case, you can let the mode do the work for the mapping. The nice thing is that this will also turn the field in a `<select>` field for `ModelForm`s derived from that model, and that for example in the `ModelAdmin` for that model, it will display the text, not the number stored in the database.

```
DUTIES = (
    (1, 'Crew'),
    (2, 'Cast'),
    (3, 'Director'),
    (4, 'Writers'),
)


class Person(models.Model):
    duty_type = models.IntegerField(choices=DUTIES)
    # …
```

then in the template we can render this as:

```
{{ person.get_duty_type_display }}
```

In this specific case, not much changes: you can use:

```
{% for person in people_details %}
    <div class="small text-gray-500">{{person.get_duty_type_display }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

There is no need at all to pass the `duties` to the template.

Answer (score 0):

If you are determined that you want to index in the template and not in the `get_context_data` method, you can write a very [simple custom template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) tag to do it. In `lookup.py`:

```
@register.filter
def lookup( d, key): 
    """ filter: d is dict-like. return d[key] with '' as default using get method """
    return d.get( key, '')
```

and in the template

```
{% load lookup %}

...

 ...  {{duties|lookup:'index'}} ...
```

( I still haven't decided whether I agree with the Django "opinionated" refusal to allow this in the supplied template facilities or not. Whenever I reach for this I feel like a workman up a ladder without a hammer using whatever is to hand to gently thump something, rather than climbing down to get a hammer. )